# Рисование спирали Python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, turtle

Задано: нарисовать Архимедову спираль в Python с помощью turtle. Нарисовал круг:

```py
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')
i = 1
while i <= 360:
    turtle.left(1)
    turtle.forward(1)
    i += 1
```

Дальше приходит в голову только вручную менять значения угла поворота черепахи через определенные пройденные ей расстояния (четверти координат). А как можно написать правильный алгоритм для именно для спирали?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что черепашка - подходящий инструмент для рисования не симметричных кривых. Отклонения будут накапливаться и в итоге всё будет перекашиваться.

Comment: Это задание из курса МФТИ - рисование разных фигур с помощью turtle, спираль - одна из них. http://judge.mipt.ru/mipt_cs_on_python3/labs/lab1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно было подключить модуль `math`, а дальше уже математика.

```py
from math import pi, sin, cos
import turtle

turtle.shape('turtle')
for i in range(200):
    t = i / 10 * pi
    dx = t * cos(t)
    dy = t * sin(t)
    turtle.goto(dx, dy)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Найдено на просторах интернета*

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi, sin, cos
from random import randint, random

RADIUS = 180  # roughly the radius of a completed spiral

screen = Screen()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

turtle.up()

for _ in range(3):
    x = randint(RADIUS - WIDTH//2, WIDTH//2 - RADIUS)
    y = randint(RADIUS - HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT//2 - RADIUS)
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
    turtle.down()

    for i in range(200):
        t = i / 20 * pi
        dx = (1 + 5 * t) * cos(t)
        dy = (1 + 5 * t) * sin(t)

        turtle.goto(x + dx, y + dy)

    turtle.up()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle
for i in range(1000):
    turtle.forward(i * 0.001)
    turtle.left(1)
```

рисует спираль, не очень понимаю зачем усложнять.

Comment: чтоб она была архимедова)

Comment: Она и есть самая что ни на есть архимедова. Замечательный короткий правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle

turtle.shape('turtle')
x = 0.5
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(30):
        turtle.forward(x)
        turtle.left(6)
    x += 0.5
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle as t
    
t.shape('turtle')  
circles = 10  
sectors = 20  
space_btw_cls = 10  
turn = 360 / sectors  
angle = 0  
    
for i in range(circles*sectors):  
    angle += turn  
    radius = space_btw_cls / 360 * angle  
    t.circle(radius, turn)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
turtle.title("rainbow!")
turtle.speed(0.5)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
r,g,b = 255,0,0

for i in range(255*2):
    turtle.colormode(255)
    if i < 255//3:
        g += 3
    elif i <255*2//3:
        r -= 3
    elif i < 255:
        b += 3
    elif i < 255*4//3:
        g -= 3
    elif i < 255*5//3:
        r += 3
    else:
        b -= 3
    turtle.fd(50+i)
    turtle.rt(91)
    turtle.pencolor(r,g,b)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]